# How to have precise time in python for timing attacks?

Tags: python, time, timing, timing-attack, side-channel-attacks

I'd like to know why python gives me two different times when I re-order the two nested for loops.
The difference is that significant that causes inaccurate results.

This one almost gives me the result I expect to see:

```
for i in range(20000):
        for j in possibleChars:
            entered_pwd = passStr + j + possibleChars[0] * leftPassLen
            st = time.perf_counter_ns()
            verify_password(stored_pwd, entered_pwd)
            endTime = time.perf_counter_ns() - st
            tmr[j] += endTime
```

But this code generate inaccurate results from my view:

```
for i in possibleChars:
        for j in range(20000):
            entered_pwd = passStr + i + possibleChars[0] * leftPassLen
            st = time.perf_counter_ns()
            verify_password(stored_pwd, entered_pwd)
            endTime = time.perf_counter_ns() - st
            tmr[i] += endTime
```

This is the function I'm attempting to run timing attack on it:

```
def verify_password(stored_pwd, entered_pwd):
    if len(stored_pwd) != len(entered_pwd):
        return False
    for i in range(len(stored_pwd)):
        if stored_pwd[i] != entered_pwd[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

I also observed a problem with character 'U' (capital case), so to have successful runs I had to delete it from my possibleChars list.
The problem is when I measure the time for 'U', it is always near double as other chars.
Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Could simply be a matter of scheduling, CPU clock changes or Python's garbage collector. The first version will scatter any temporary disturbance in performance across all characters. The second tests one character at one time so it will be more heavily affected

Comment: @Homer512, thank you, but you know, I run the code 20000 times to make sure that CPU clock changes affect my code equally for different characters.

Comment: Well, did you try reversing the list of characters, or changing the number of iterations? Does it affect which character causes trouble?

Comment: I also suggest keeping track of the variance. Just run the online algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance) It would give you a good indication whether you are affected by differences in runtime and may allow you to throw away outliers

Comment: @Homer512, aside from 'U', it happens randomly, I mean each time it shows me a different character. so, probably it's not about the range of possible chars I use and I didn't include  (!,@,#, etc.) in my list

Comment: Well, you count wall clock time. All that needs to happen is the OS scheduling something else to run to throw off the timing, or even just an interrupt coming in on the current CPU core. That's why you need to control for outliers.

Answer (score 1):

Summing up the timings may not be a good idea here: 
One interruption due to e.g., scheduling will have a huge effect on the total and may completely invalidate your measurements. 
Iterating like in the first loop is probably more likely to spread noise more evenly across the measurements (this is just an educated guess though). 
However, it would be better to use the median or minimum time instead of the sum. 
This way, you eliminate all noisy measurements.

That being said, I don't expect the timing difference to be huge and python being a high-level language will generate more noisy measurements compared to more low-level languages (because of garbage collection and so on).

But it still works :) 
I've implemented an example relying on the minimum time (instead of the sum).
On my local machine, it works reliably except for the last character, where the timing difference is way smaller:

```
import time
import string
# We want to leak this
stored_pwd = "S3cret"

def verify_password(entered_pwd):
    if len(stored_pwd) != len(entered_pwd):
        return False
    for i in range(len(stored_pwd)):
        if stored_pwd[i] != entered_pwd[i]:
            return False
    return True

possibleChars = string.printable
MEASUREMENTS = 2000 # works even with numbers as small as 20 (for me)

def find_char(prefix, len_pwd):
    tmr = {i: 9999999999 for i in possibleChars}
    for i in possibleChars:
        for j in range(MEASUREMENTS):
            entered_pwd = prefix + i + i * (len_pwd - len(prefix) - 1)
            st = time.perf_counter_ns()
            verify_password(entered_pwd)
            endTime = time.perf_counter_ns() - st
            tmr[i] = min(endTime, tmr[i])
    return max(tmr.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]                        

def find_length(max_length = 100):
    tmr = [99999999 for i in range(max_length + 1)]
    for i in range(max_length + 1):
        for j in range(MEASUREMENTS):
            st = time.perf_counter_ns()
            verify_password("X" * i)
            endTime = time.perf_counter_ns() - st
            tmr[i] = min(endTime, tmr[i])
    return max(enumerate(tmr), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]    

length = find_length()
print(f"password length: {length}")

recovered_password = ""
for i in range(length):
    recovered_password += find_char(recovered_password, length)
    print(f"{recovered_password}{'?' * (length - len(recovered_password))}")

print(f"Password: {recovered_password}")
```